# How to use values in ANT GroupBox for CheckBoxes?

Tags: reactjs, antd, groupbox, ant-design-pro

I am using ANT Checkboxes and GroupBox, i need to have ability to check and uncheck all checkboxes at once.
In order to do that i used ANT  recomended way of implementation checkboxes GroupBox.
Everything worked great but i can't now asing values in checkboxes and there no documentation about it on ANT website.
For instance when i use array of strings everything works but when i use array of objects which is also recomended to use on ANT it doens't work.
If i asing variable this everything works

```
const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'];
```

But when i use it with objects it doens't

```
const plainOptions = [{label: 'Apple', value: '1'}, {label: 'Orange', value: '2'}];
```

I don't understand it what's is the point of using checkboxes if they can't  have values :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Card, Button, Space, Row, Col, Input, Select, Modal, Checkbox, Form } from 'antd';

 const { Option } = Select;
 const CheckboxGroup = Checkbox.Group;




 const Content= () => {
  const plainOptions = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange']; //This works
  //This doesn't work, but it should.
  //const plainOptions = [{label: 'Apple', value: '1'}, {label: 'Orange', value: '2'}];


  const defaultCheckedList = [];
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = useState(defaultCheckedList);
  const [indeterminate, setIndeterminate] = useState(true);
  const [checkAll, setCheckAll] = useState(false);



  const onChange = list => {
   setCheckedList(list);
   setIndeterminate(!!list.length && list.length < plainOptions.length);
   setCheckAll(list.length === plainOptions.length);
  };

  const onCheckAllChange = e => {
   setCheckedList(e.target.checked ? plainOptions : []);
   setIndeterminate(false);
   setCheckAll(e.target.checked);
  };




return(
 <div>
  <Checkbox
    indeterminate={indeterminate}
    onChange={onCheckAllChange}
    checked={checkAll}
   >
    All
   </Checkbox>

    <CheckboxGroup
      className="vertical-checkbox-group"
      options={plainOptions}
      value={checkedList}
      onChange={onChange}
     />
   </div>
  )
 }
```

export default Content;
Does anyone maybe know how to do it properly? , i know also some people do it with for loop but i afraid it's wrong way of implementation and it make create new issues.
Using objects with labels and values is also recomended way of implementetion by ANT but it doesn't work for GroupBox.

Comment: Hi Vlad - can you put a minimal example into a code sharing tool so we can play around?

Comment: Hi Markido, this is the minimal example of code which is required to implement GroupBox according to ANT

Comment: Hi Vlad - if you can share it as a runable snippet we have a better shared way to problem solve :-)

Comment: Where you have `setCheckedList(e.target.checked ? plainOptions : []);`, if your options is an array of objects, then pass the array of values rather than the entire array, e.g. `setCheckedList(e.target.checked ? plainOptions.map(e => e.value) : []);`